# Accessing a named column of a data frame using a variable which holds the name

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose `data` is a `data.frame`. I wish to access `data$field`, without knowing the name `field` in advance; instead, I have a variable `varfield` which holds the string `'field'`, and I wish to use that variable to access the column in `data` whose name is the value of `varfield`.

Can this be done?

Comment: Elegant! I didn't know that... If you just write it down as an answer, I'll accept that, thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're talking about columns rather than rows to me though. If that's the case, it would be good to edit the question title and text for others who read this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[` instead of `$` and use `varfield` for subseting, just like this:

```
data[,varfield]
```